# zpool: pool I/O is currently suspended

Tags: macos, mount, disk-utility, zfs

I'm using [ZFS on OSX](https://github.com/zfs-osx/zfs) and I've zpool which is active and online:

```
NAME      SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
WD_1TB    931G   280G   651G    30%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

but I can't actually mount it.

```
$ sudo zfs mount WD_1TB
cannot open 'WD_1TB': pool I/O is currently suspended
cannot open 'WD_1TB': pool I/O is currently suspended
```

or unmount it:

```
$ sudo zfs unmount WD_1TB
cannot open 'WD_1TB': pool I/O is currently suspended
cannot open 'WD_1TB': pool I/O is currently suspended
```

or even destroy it:

```
$ sudo zpool destroy -f WD_1TB
cannot open 'WD_1TB': pool I/O is currently suspended
```

When doing `zpool export WD_1TB` it just freezes.

When clearing device errors in a pool, there is an error as well:

```
$ sudo zpool clear WD_1TB
cannot clear errors for WD_1TB: I/O error
```

Above happening whatever the disk is connected via USB or not.

What's interesting that `zpool status` points zpool to /dev/disk1, but `diskutil list` points to /dev/disk3.

I've enabled debug messages via: `sysctl -w zfs.vnops_osx_debug=1` and run `sudo dmesg | tail` which shows something like:

```
0 [Level 3] [Facility com.apple.system.fs] [ErrType IO] [ErrNo 6] [IOType Read] [PBlkNum 0] [LBlkNum 0] 
0 [Level 3] [Facility com.apple.system.fs] [DevNode devfs] [MountPt /dev] [Path /dev/disk1s2] 
disk1s2: media is not present.
0 [Level 3] [Facility com.apple.system.fs] [ErrType IO] [ErrNo 6] [IOType Read] [PBlkNum 512] [LBlkNum 512] 
0 [Level 3] [Facility com.apple.system.fs] [DevNode devfs] [MountPt /dev] [Path /dev/disk1s2] 

zfs_vnop_write(vp 0xffffff804f6303c0, offset 0x12b00000 size 0x10000
zfs_vnop_write(vp 0xffffff804f6303c0, offset 0x12b10000 size 0x10000
zfs_vnop_write(vp 0xffffff804f6303c0, offset 0x12b20000 size 0x10000
zfs_vnop_write(vp 0xffffff804f6303c0, offset 0x12b30000 size 0x10000
zfs_vnop_write(vp 0xffffff8051b031e0, offset 0x1f0000 size 0x10000
```

Connecting or disconnecting HDD doesn't help.

Any way of simply mounting the HDD on OSX in above circumstances?

Related:

- [Unable to destroy ZFS pool](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2546634)

Comment: Some ZFS commands accept a `-f` flag to force operations that might normally fail. Have you tried this flag?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. E.g. zfs mount doesn't accept `-f`. Restarting OSX helped for few days, but it keeps happening from time to time.

Comment: btw. `zpool destroy -f WD_1TB` shows the same error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If executing `sudo zpool clear WD_1TB` won't work, try:

```
$ sudo zpool clear -nFX WD_1TB
```

where these undocumented parameters mean:

> - `-F`: (undocumented for `clear`, the same as for `import`) Rewind. Recovery mode for a non-importable pool. Attempt to return the pool to an importable state by discarding the last few transactions. Not all damaged pools can be recovered by using this option. If successful,  the  data from the discarded transactions is irretrievably lost. This option is ignored if the pool is importable or already imported.
> - `-n`: (undocumented for `clear`, the same as for `import`) Used  with  the  `-F` recovery option. Determines whether a non-importable pool can be made importable again, but does not actually perform the pool recovery. For more details about pool recovery mode, see the -F option, above.
>     and then try to re-import again:
> - `-X` (undocumented): Extreme rewind. The effect of -X
>     seems to be that some extremely lengthy operation is attempted, that
>     never finishes. In some cases, a reboot was necessary to terminate the
>     process.
> - `-V` (undocumented): Option by UTSLing, when used for `import` it makes the pool got imported again, but still without an attempt at resilvering.

<sup>Source: [ZFS faulted pool problem](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2012-February/066215.html) and `man zpool`.</sup>

```
$ zpool import WD_1TB
```

---

If won't help, try the following commands to remove the invalid zpool:

```
$ zpool list -v
$ sudo zfs unmount WD_1TB
$ sudo zpool destroy -f WD_1TB
$ zpool detach WD_1TB disk1s2
$ zpool remove WD_1TB disk1s2
$ zpool remove WD_1TB /dev/disk1s2
$ zpool set cachefile=/etc/zfs/zpool.cache WD_1TB
```

---

Finally if nothing helps, remove the file `/etc/zfs/zpool.cache` (optionally) and just restart your computer.

---

Related:

- [zfs-osx/zfs on GitHub: zpool: pool I/O is currently suspended](https://github.com/zfs-osx/zfs/issues/104)
- [zfsonlinux/zfs on GitHub: Removing cache device fails](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/1530)
- [How to get rid of phantom pool?](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.solaris.opensolaris.zfs/45153)
- [zfs export and import between diferent controllers](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=6005)
- [How do I generate the /etc/zfs/zpool.cache file](http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#HowDoIGenerateTheZpoolCacheFile)
- [Princeton University: ZFS Troubleshoot](http://www.princeton.edu/~unix/Solaris/troubleshoot/zfs.html)

Comment: This saved my butt when I hot swapped a few drives and screwed up my pool. I didn't used the `-x` flag, just `-nF`